# How to get Azure Traffic Manager endpoint profiles with C#

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, azure-traffic-manager

I need to get the load balanced endpoints that a Traffic Manager endpoint is balancing over. How do you do that with C#?

It looks like I need to create an instance of `TrafficManagerManagementClient`, which wants an object of type `SubscriptionCloudCredentials`. I see there is a `TokenCloudCredentials` derived class that I can use for this. This takes a `token`, which is described as "Valid JSON Web Token (JWT).".

So how do I get a Valid JSON Web Token (JWT)?

Comment: Please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx. 1st option (Authenticate using Azure Active Directory) is what you want. HTH.

Comment: That model implies I'm in a web context, which I'm not. This is a console that doesn't have a web interface to do the OAuth dance. This leads me to think TokenCloudCredentials just might not be the right way to try to authenticate. I'll look into using CertificateCloudCredentials.

Comment: Step 4 (in the link I shared), you can create a console application as well. Also see this example on Azure AD + Native Client: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet. But I do agree that going CertificateCloudCredentials route is much easier though more and more services are going in favor or Azure AD. HTH.